# Redefinition error: howto fix?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#define SIZEDTEXT struct mail_sizedtext

SIZEDTEXT {
  unsigned char *data;      /* text */
  unsigned long size;       /* size of text in octets */
};
```

Howto fix this redefinition error?

1>c:....\mail.h(624): error C2011: 'mail_sizedtext': 'struct' type redefinition

Comment: do you use header guards?

Comment: I didn't. Now, the error vanished. I'll have to use many of them, but I guess there's no other way round. Thank you!

Comment: np :)..........